# how to do binary search on array which is the numbers on even indexes are ascending and the numbers on odd indexes are descending

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

how to do binary search on array which is the numbers on even indexes are ascending and the numbers on odd indexes are descending example the array {-3,10,0,9,5,0,7,-1} and i want to find a number : x=5

i think i should do binary search on even indexes alone, and on odd indexes alone

Comment: What is the use-case for such a bizarre data organization?

Comment: Yes, I think you can simply think of it like 2 separated sorted arrays, and then do binary search on each of them individually.

Comment: i want a time complexity to be O(log(n)) @HungThai

Comment: It's `O(log(n))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two binary searches, one for the increasing and decreasing values each. There will be a few simple modifications:

1. The bounds will not be `[0, n-1]` (where `n` is the length of array). The opening and closing limit will be different for the descending and ascending values respectively.
2. Instead of adjusting `low = mid + 1` or `high = mid - 1`, you'll use `low = mid + 2` and `high = mid - 2` so that the parity of the middle index doesn't change during the search.

Since this is a simple task, I'll leave the formal algorithm for the reader to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can perform two separate binary searches. One on

```
(-3,0,5,0,7)
```

and the other on

```
(-1,0,9,10).
```

As regards the implementation, you can use a standard algorithm and

- replace all indexes by their double (`i` becomes `2i`) for the first search;
- replace all indexes by `m-2i` where `m` is `n` or `n-1`, whichever is odd for the second search.

---

You cannot do with a single search, replacing the even indexes by `2i` and the odd ones by `m-2i` because there is no guarantee that this would correspond to a growing sequence (e.g. `(-3,-1,0,0,5,9,7,10)`). A preliminary merge is required, taking linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```
//time complexity O(log(n))
      public static int find(int[] a, int x) {
        int bottom = 0 , top = 0 , mid=0;
        if(a.length % 2 == 0 ) {
            top = a.length - 2;
        }
        else
        {
            top = a.length - 1;
        }
        while (bottom <= top ) {
            mid = (bottom + top) / 2;
            mid -= mid % 2;//round down to the nearest even index
            if (a[mid] > x) {
                top = mid - 2;
            }
            else if (a[mid] < x) {
                bottom = mid + 2;
            }
            else {
                return  mid;
            }
        }

        bottom = 1 ; top=0; mid=0;
        if(a.length % 2 == 0 ) {
            top = a.length - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            top = a.length - 2;
        }
        while (bottom <= top ) {
            mid = (bottom + top) / 2;
            mid -= (mid + 1) % 2;// round down to the nearest odd index
            if (a[mid] < x)
            {
                top = mid - 2;
            }
            else if (a[mid] > x) {
                bottom = mid + 2;
            }
            else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).